# find the best possible bound for $|f(1/4)|?$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Given $f$ analytic in $|z| < 2,$ bounded there by $2$, and such that $f(1) = 0,$ find the best possible bound for $|f(1/4)|?$

My attempt : I found the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/181301/557708)
But this solution is  not correct because it contain some mistake

Mistake  is $h(z):=\phi(g(\phi^{—1}(z)))$ doesn't satisfy schwarz lemma  since $h(0)\neq0$

**My solution** : Take $g(z)= \frac{f(2z)}{2}$ and take $\phi(z)= \frac{z-1/2}{1-1/2z}$

then $\phi^{-1}(z)=\frac{z+1/2}{1+1/2z}    $

take $ h(z)= g \circ  \phi^{-1}(z)  = g(\phi^{-1}(z))$

put $z=0 $, then $ h(0)=                 g(1/2)  $

we have  $ g(1/2)= f(1)/2=0  $

Therefor $h(0)=0 $, and $h$ satisfy the schwarz lemma  i,e  $|h(z)|\le |z|$

This implies  that $| g(z)| \le |\phi(z)| $

$g(1/8)  = \frac{1/8-1/2}{1-1/2.(1/8)} =2/5$

$2.g(1/8)=f(1/4)\implies f(1/4)=\frac{4}{5}   $

so the     the best possible bound for $|f(1/4)|$ is $\frac{4}{5}$

Is my solution is correct or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct, only that it should be
$$
 |g(1/8)| \le  \left| \frac{1/8 - 1/2}{1-(1/2)(1/8)}\right| = \frac 25
$$
instead of $g(1/8) = 2/5$, and therefore $|f(1/4)| \le 4/5$, not $f(1/4) = 4/5$.

You also have to show that this is the best possible bound. This can be achieved by choosing $f$ such that $h(z) = z$ or equivalently, $g(z) = \phi(z)$, that is
$$
 f(z) = 2 \phi(\frac z2) = 2 \frac{z/2 - 1/2}{1-(1/2)(z/2)} = \frac{4(z-1)}{4z-1} \, .
$$
This function satisfies the given conditions with $f(1/4) = -4/5$, so that the bound is sharp.

In other words: If $f$ is analytic in $|z| < 2$ with $|f(z)| < 2$ and $f(1) = 0$ then
$$
 f(z) = 2 h(\phi(\frac z2))
$$
where $\phi(z) = \frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}$ and $h$ maps the unit disk into itself with $h(0) = 0$. It follows that
$$
 |f(z)| \le 2 \left| \phi(\frac z2) \right|
$$
with equality if $h(z) = \lambda z$ with some $\lambda$ of modulus one.